# Возврат значения по условию

Tags: javascript

Существует функция:

```
function some_f() {
    this.first = function () {
        //code
    }
    this.second = function () {
        //code
    }
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при первом запуске возвращался только метод `first`, а при любых последующих только `second`. Например:

```
some_f().second()//ошибка
//именно в такой последовательности:
some_f().first();//верно
some_f().first();//ошибка
some_f().second();//верно
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function some_f() {
    if (some_f.counter == undefined) some_f.counter = 0;
    some_f.counter++;

    this.first = function () {
        alert('first');
    }
    this.second = function () {
        alert('second');
    }
    if (some_f.counter > 1)     {
        return this.second()
    }else {
        return this.first();
    }
}
```